# Place a Kivy ActionCheck next to an ActionLabel

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

The problem I'm facing is including a Checkbox in my ActionGroup with a Label beside it.

In the conventional case I'd use a Layout class for aligning the Checkbox next to a widget. But in the ActionView or ActionGroup only ActionItems are allowed as children.

I tried so far to place the CheckBox into the ActionLabel, which resulted into a misplaced and transparent background ActionItem ([Checkbox above the ActionLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6XGr.png)):

```
ActionGroup:
id: view_menu_group
text: "[color=ff9900]View[/color]"
markup: True
mode: "spinner"

ActionLabel:
    text: "Compare Mode"
    ActionCheck:
        on_active: app.root.main_view.graph.multi_plot = self.active
```

My aim should look similar to this: [Menu Dropdown with Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjNXQ.png)

Comment: Your project looks very interesting! Please tell me what you're plotting in a comment.

Comment: Thank you! I'm plotting force-extension curves from atomic force microscopic data

Comment: Wow, that's super interesting. Best of luck in your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what we do: we can actually place any kind of widget or layout in an ActionGroup. For some reason kivy decided that we can only do that if we inherit from ActionItem. But, basically, the code is the same:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
<MyCheckbox@BoxLayout+ActionItem>: # Inheritance in .kv
    ActionLabel:
        text: "Hello"
    ActionCheck:

ActionBar:
    size_hint: 1, 0.1 # REMOVE ME
    pos_hint: {'top':1} # REMOVE ME

    id: view_menu_group
    text: "[color=ff9900]View[/color]"
    markup: True
    mode: "spinner"

    ActionView:
        ActionPrevious:  # need this for some unknown reason
        ActionGroup:
            MyCheckbox:  # our custom Label+Checkbox ActionItem
'''))
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: Label next to checkbox in an ActionBar ActionGroup]

Comment: Works perfectly! Now I just have to get the background of the label to a non transparent one. Thanks a lot! :)